# How to set default range selected on chart draw in Highcharts/Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I set default range selected without using the:

```
rangeSelector:{
  selected: 3
}
```

The reason why I want to do that is that I am trying to develop a custom range selector of my own. Also can I also ask why I'm getting a broken chart once I press the YTD again. Here is a link to my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/Gpb56/2/) and my sample code:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
        $('.zoom_controls a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // OK, pretty ugly :)
            var call = 'zoom' + $(this).attr('data-range');
            // I have two globally accessible charts here:
            if ($(this).attr('data-chart') == 'line') {
                lineChart[call]();
            } else {
                candleChart[call]();
            }
            $(this).addClass('active');

        });
        var proto = Highcharts.Chart.prototype;
        proto.zoomToD = function (delta) {
            var chartMin = this.xAxis[1].min;
            var chartMax = this.xAxis[0].max;
            var min = chartMax - delta;

            if (chartMin < min) {
                // this.xAxis[0] is the view, this.xAxis[1] is the navigator
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, chartMax);
                this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(this.series[0].dataMin, this.series[0].dataMax);
                return true;
            }

            this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chartMin, chartMax);
            this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(this.series[0].dataMin, this.series[0].dataMax);
            return false;
        };

        proto.zoom3m = function () {
            return this.zoomToD(2592000 * 3 * 1000);
        };
        proto.zoom6m = function () {
            return this.zoomToD(2592000 * 6 * 1000);
        };
        proto.zoom1y = function () {
            return this.zoomToD(2592000 * 12 * 1000);
        };
        proto.zoom2y = function () {
            return this.zoomToD(2592000 * 24 * 1000);
        };
        proto.zoom3y = function () {
            return this.zoomToD(2592000 * 36 * 1000);
        };
        proto.zoom5y = function () {
            return this.zoomToD(2592000 * 60 * 1000);
        };
        proto.zoom10y = function () {
            return this.zoomToD(2592000 * 120 * 1000);
        };
        proto.zoomYtd = function () {
            var chartMin = this.xAxis[1].min;
            var chartMax = this.xAxis[1].max;
            var min = chartMax - 2592000 * 12 * 1000;

            if (chartMin < min) {
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, chartMax);
                return true;
            }

            this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chartMin, chartMax);
            return false;
        }

        /*And then I define some stuff that instantiates Highcharts.StockChart objects, e.g.:*/
        lineChart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'area'


            },

            series: [{
                id: "data",
                name: 'HP',
                data: data,
                color: '#7BA6A5',
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }],

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    year: '%Y',
                    month: '%m',
                    week: '%b %e'
                },
                gridLineWidth: 1

            },

            yAxis: {
                opposite: false,
                minorTickInterval: 'auto'
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: false

            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
        lineChart.scroller.xAxis.labelGroup.hide();
        lineChart.scroller.xAxis.gridGroup.hide();
        lineChart.scroller.series.hide();
        lineChart.scroller.scrollbar.hide();
        lineChart.scroller.scrollbarGroup.hide();
        lineChart.scroller.navigatorGroup.hide();
        lineChart.scroller.scrollbarTrack.hide();
        $.each(lineChart.scroller.elementsToDestroy, function (i, elem) {
            elem.hide();
        });
        lineChart.rangeSelector.zoomText.hide();
        /*$.each(lineChart.rangeSelector.buttons, function () {
            this.hide();
        });*/
        /*lineChart.rangeSelector.inputEnabled = false;*/

    });
});
```

Any help or guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by setting an initial `setExtremes function`. Please take a look at my updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/Gpb56/9/)

Answer (score 12):

Simply use:

```
xAxis: {
    min: timestampFrom,
    max: timestampTo
}
```

About your second issue, if you are doing multiple updates, then you should be disabling animations for all execpt last one. See fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gpb56/3/

Comment: Fus Thanks for that I had to modify it a bit because the second one is causing an error About my first issue I forgot to specify how can I set it to say 1 year?

Comment: Just difference between `timestampTo` and `timestampFrom` should be one year (something about 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000).

Comment: Fus Also for tooltips I'm having this weird bug were chinese characters are showing in my tooltips in jsfiddle but not on my actual application please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/Gpb56/7/

Comment: jsFiddle is using UTF-8 encoding. Set the same for your site AND for your file.

Comment: Fus I noticed that the Initial 1 year set is different from the 1year displayed when clicking the 1y button why is that, is there anyway to make them similar?